# Storing millions of data points in react

Tags: reactjs, performance

Where do I store response from an third party API call without hindering performance, also storing it in state variable is causing performance issues. I also want to render all these points on a chart at a time no pagination, no batching I want render all of them, more or less like a trading chart.

I found pagination and lazy loading when i was searching for optimization techniques both of which i can't use here.

Comment: This question needs a lot more details to be answerable. Millions of data points? At full HD, you have about 2 million pixels to work with. If every data point is represented by a single pixel, you can have at most 2 million data points to fill your entire screen.

Comment: For storage, you could consider the browser's local storage, but that runs up to about 10 MB. If you have very small data points, let's say a 4 byte integer, you can store at most 2.5 million.